# When did the Avengers have their first confrontation with the Phoenix Force?

Tags: marvel, comics, avengers, phoenix-force

I have been a long-time reader of the Avengers and cannot actually remember the first time the Avengers had a direct confrontation with the Phoenix Force.

- Have the Avengers ever directly confronted the Phoenix Force in combat?
- What was the outcome and what Avengers were involved?
- Is their reaction to the supposed return of the Phoenix based on the information they may have gathered from second hand sources?

The only Avengers I know that might have had direct experience with Phoenix or the Phoenix Force are the Beast and Wolverine (from their time as X-men).

Comment: Why was the tag Avengers vs X-men removed from this thread? It is directly related to Avengers AND Avengers vs X-men.

Comment: The tag was removed because it is for the specific mini series being released this month, and not every incident of a conflict between members of X-men and members of the Avengers. For reference, please see [this meta discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/does-the-tagavengers-vs-x-men-tag-refer-to-the-cross-over-comics-or-the-cont). Admittedly, I'm not terribly familiar with the material, but your question seems like you are looking for the history of what has already occurred, and not what is happening in the specific mini series that tag is for.

Comment: Feel free to add it back if I am wrong, however, and this question is really directly relevant to the events of the upcoming mini-series, rather than "when in past comics did Avengers confront the Phoenix Force for the first time".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can gather no Avengers team has ever directly encountered the Phoenix Force, nor the Phoenix (Jean Grey). The closest I can see is, as you mentioned, Beast's involvement as well as links between Excalibur and the Avengers.

> The escape of Phoenix from Mojo's realm served as a catalyst to unite the five as a team, initially working together to prevent both Roma's agents the Technet and Mojo's Warwolves from recapturing his former prisoner.

Excalibur and the Avengers teaming up is probably the first instance where they could have learnt of the Phoenix Force, though I do not know of an issue where this directly occurs.

> Subsequently Excalibur ... fought alongside some of the Avengers in Wakanda against Icon...

All quotes from the [Excalibur](http://marvel.com/universe/Excalibur) page on Marvel.com